# Pandas Lag over multiple columns and set number of iterations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
```

I would like to apply the pandas shift function to shift each column 4 times and create a new row for each shift:

```
col1 col1.lag0 col1.lag1 col1.lag2 col1.lag3 col2 col2.lag0 col2.lag1 col2.lag2 col2.lag3
1    0         0         0         0         3    0         0         0         0
2    1         0         0         0         4    3         0         0         0
0    2         1         0         0         0    4         3         0         0
0    0         2         1         0         0    0         4         3         0
0    0         0         2         1         0    0         0         4         3
```

I have tried a few solutions with shift like `d['col1'].shift().fillna(0)`, however, I am not sure how to iterate the solution nor how to ensure the correct number of rows are added to the dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I extend the given DataFrame by the correct number of rows with zeros. Then iterate over the columns and the amount of shifts to create the desired columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
n_shifts = 4
zero_rows = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.RangeIndex(n_shift_rows), columns=df.columns).fillna(0)
df = df.append(zero_rows).reset_index(drop=True)

for col in df.columns:
    for shift_amount in range(1, n_shifts+1):
        df[f"{col}.lag{shift_amount}"] = df[col].shift(shift_amount)
df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

As pointed out by Ben.T the outer loop can be avoided as `shift` can be applied at once on the whole DataFrame. An alternative for the looping would be

```
shifts = df
for shift_amount in range(1, n_shifts+1):
    columns = df.columns + ".lag" + str(shift_amount)
    shift = pd.DataFrame(df.shift(shift_amount).values, columns=columns)
    shifts = shifts.join(shift)
shifts.fillna(0).astype(int)
```